# List of lists of tuples, group by first element and add second elements

Tags: python, list, tuples

Let's say I have the following list of lists of tuples:

```
tuples = [
             [ 
                 ('2017-04-11', '2000000.00'), 
                 ('2017-04-12', '1000000.00'), 
                 ('2017-04-13', '3000000.00')
             ],
             [
                 ('2017-04-12', '472943.00'), 
                 ('2017-04-13', '1000000.00')
             ]
             # ...
         ]
```

How would I go about grouping them based off of the first element (date) and adding the other element.

For instance I'd like something like this:

```
tuples = [('2017-04-11', '2000000.00'), ('2017-04-12', '1472943.00'), ('2017-04-13', '4000000.00')],
```

Comment: So you've posted your input and your expected result. But where's your approach on solving the problem on your own? Please post your code and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: By seeing expected output could not understand clear. But:
Make group identity as key and create a dictionary out of that. `{ "group-identity", [your-list-mentioned-above] }`. create data in this format using python. Is this what you looking for?

Comment: I've asked a question, because I tried numerous solutions and couldn't get it to work. I tried map, itertools.izip_longest without any luck @mpf82

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, `itertools.groupby` and `sum` functions:

```
import itertools, operator

tuples = [
         [('2017-04-11', '2000000.00'), ('2017-04-12', '1000000.00'), ('2017-04-13', '3000000.00')],
         [('2017-04-12', '472943.00'), ('2017-04-13', '1000000.00')]
         ]

result = [(k, "%.2f" % sum(float(t[1]) for t in g)) 
          for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(itertools.chain.from_iterable(tuples)), operator.itemgetter(0))]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('2017-04-11', '2000000.00'), ('2017-04-12', '1472943.00'), ('2017-04-13', '4000000.00')]
```

Answer (score 3):

First, flat a list of tuples out of a list of lists of tuples, and then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby),

```
import itertools 
import operator

lists = [
         [('2017-04-11', '2000000.00'), ('2017-04-12', '1000000.00'), ('2017-04-13', '3000000.00')],
         [('2017-04-12', '472943.00'), ('2017-04-13', '1000000.00')]
         ]

# Step 1: Flat a list of tuples out of a list of lists of tuples
list_tuples = [t for sublist in lists for t in sublist]
'''
[('2017-04-11', '2000000.00'), ('2017-04-12', '1000000.00'), ('2017-04-13', '3000000.00'), ('2017-04-12', '472943.00'), ('2017-04-13', '1000000.00')]
'''

# Step 2: Groupby
results = list()

for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(list_tuples), operator.itemgetter(0)):
    s = sum(float(t[1]) for t in group)
    results.append((key, s))

print(results)
#[('2017-04-11', 2000000.0), ('2017-04-12', 1472943.0), ('2017-04-13', 4000000.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

My way is to convert the nested list to flat list and iterate it:

```
t = [
         [('2017-04-11', '2000000.00'), ('2017-04-12', '1000000.00'), ('2017-04-13', '3000000.00')],
         [('2017-04-12', '472943.00'), ('2017-04-13', '1000000.00')]
         ]
a={}

for i,j in sum(t,[]):
    a[i]=a[i]+float(j) if i in a else float(j)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'2017-04-11': 2000000.0, '2017-04-13': 4000000.0, '2017-04-12': 1472943.0}
```

If you want a list, you can use `[(k,v) for k,v in a.items()])`

Answer (score 0):

Flattening the list then using defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

flattened_tuples = [item for sublist in tuples for item in sublist]

result = defaultdict(float)
for date, value in flattened_tuples:
    result[date] += float(value)
print(result)
```

returns
`{'2017-04-11': 2000000.0, '2017-04-12': 1472943.0, '2017-04-13': 4000000.0}`