# Plotting elements from a list

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have a list of lists, such as:

```
['010', '01', '7']
['010', '02', '6']
['010', '03', '24']
['010', '04', '6']
['015', '02', '8']
['015', '03', '27']
['015', '04', '27']
['020', '01', '130']
['020', '02', '140']
['020', '03', '202']
['020', '04', '3']
['021', '01', '3']
['021', '02', '4']
['021', '03', '22']
['021', '04', '1']
['025', '01', '13']
['025', '02', '52']
['025', '03', '82']
```

The first element represents an ID, second element the month and third element the total amount.
How can I plot the total amounts by month? I would like to have an individual line for each ID.

I tried something similar to the below:

```
for i in output:
    plt.plot(int(i[1]). int(i[2]))

plt.show()
```

Is returning a blank line. Additionally, I am not sure how to handle legends as well.

[image]

Comment: use plt.scatter(int(i[1]), int(i[2]))

Comment: conversion is done in the loop already. the problem here is that it is not meaningful to plot a line between one point

Comment: @tyasia16: read my answer below. Does it answer your concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `pandas`. I assumed you list of lists is named `l`

```
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
arr = np.array(l).astype(np.int)

for id_, g in pd.DataFrame(arr).groupby(0):
    ax.plot(g[1], g[2], label=id_)

ax.legend()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas dataframes to label and plot your data:

```
import pandas as pd
l = [['010', '01', '7'],
['010', '02', '6'],
['010', '03', '24'],
['010', '04', '6'],
['015', '02', '8'],
['015', '03', '27'],
['015', '04', '27'],
['020', '01', '130'],
['020', '02', '140'],
['020', '03', '202'],
['020', '04', '3'],
['021', '01', '3'],
['021', '02', '4'],
['021', '03', '22'],
['021', '04', '1'],
['025', '01', '13'],
['025', '02', '52'],
['025', '03', '82']]

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['ID','Month','Amount'])
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].astype(int)

df.groupby(['Month','ID'])['Amount'].sum().unstack().plot()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I like your solution ;} +1

Comment: @RafaelC  Thank you.  I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

[this pic for plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FOUI.png) try this code

```
@Output
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
output = [['010', '01', '7'],
['010', '02', '6'],
['010', '03', '24'],
['010', '04', '6'],
['015', '02', '8'],
['015', '03', '27'],
['015', '04', '27'],
['020', '01', '130'],
['020', '02', '140'],
['020', '03', '202'],
['020', '04', '3'],
['021', '01', '3'],
['021', '02', '4'],
['021', '03', '22'],
['021', '04', '1'],
['025', '01', '13'],
['025', '02', '52'],
['025', '03', '82']]


listx = []
listy = []
for i in output:
    listx.append((i[1]))
    listy.append((i[2]))
plt.plot(listx,listy,'ro')
@Output(plt.show())
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to group the values based on the first column. This can be done using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43391639/4932316) suggestion for example. Then you need to convert your string values to floats. This can be done using `map()` among other possible ways. `[:, 1:]` specifies indexing which means all the rows `:` and then second and third columns `1:`

Below is a working answer assuming that your input is stored in a variable called `data`.

EDIT: I took the suggestion of @RafaelC to convert the data type to float using `astype(float)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools, operator

# data = [[...], [...], [...]]

for k,g in itertools.groupby(data, operator.itemgetter(0)):
    arr = np.array(list(g))[:, 1:].astype(float)
    x = arr[:, 0]
    y = arr[:, 1]
    plt.plot(x, y, label=k)
plt.legend()  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Solution appears to work, but am not able to display the legends

Comment: @tyasia16: Did you use `plt.legend()` at the end like I do?

Comment: Also like the use of itertools, even though I think pandas is more inutiitve. May use `astype(float)` instead of `map` cause iterating over numpy arrays is costly +1 ;)